# Why does my terminal stop responding ocasionally?

Tags: ssh

I use SSH to work on my Raspberry using the PC as a terminal, and it normally works just fine.  But once in a while, the Pi just stops responding.  For example, I'll use up-arrow to repeat a command, and nothing happens for 5 to 10 seconds, then the screen responds.  Or I'll type a command and the PC screen just sits there for a few seconds, then the command is echoed and executed.

This is just an annoyance as it only happens once every few minutes, but if anyone has some insight to what's happening, I would appreciate it.

It does also happen on the Pi console, but not as often.

TIA

Comment: It's likely either network latency, or because the Pi is busy.  You may want to clarify 1) How you are connected -- home WLAN etc. 2) What else the Pi may be doing.

Comment: I saw this last year - don't remember the fix. There is a discussion at [Pi3 Stutters over WiFi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=146077&p=980987&hilit=ssh%20pause#p980987)

Comment: I was getting this shortly before the SD card went to SD heaven - check output of `dmesg` for errors regarding `/dev/mmcblk0*`

Answer (score 1):

Check how is your power supply and cable situation - run:
 vcgencmd get_throttled

0x50005 <- first 5 means throttling occurred, last 5 means you are suffering from "brown outs" on your power supply.